# How to find the right version of Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, jenkins

I'm currently working on a build pipeline that uses [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) and [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) to trigger builds for the project. Basically, the build is triggered when someone pushes to the repository. Also, some Ruby scripts are executed as part of the build process. These scripts run some checks on the projects and perform some fixes, like synchronizing an Xcode project with added and deleted files from the source directory - in this case they are not the same.

I'm using several tools to configure the pipeline. The builds run on a machine that is physically located on the build slave. Jenkins is deployed to an AWS machine. For this reason, I used [pritunl](https://pritunl.com/) to connect the two on a virtual network. I can use local IPs to communicate between the machines and SSH is working fine both ways.

When I push to the remote the build starts correctly on the slave, but it fails to complete. However, if I manually access using SSH through the terminal, the build performs fine. This is the output I get from Jenkins:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/jenkins/workspace/Core/platform/ios/scripts/pbxsync.rb:58:in `<main>'
```

As you can see, it fails to require [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj), causing the build to fail. Still, this only happens if the build is triggered by Jenkins, not manually.

This makes me think that Jenkins is using some different installation of Ruby, or at least a different environment. Basically what I need is to install gems for the same Ruby environment that Jenkins is using, but I don't know which one that is. Any ideas?

---

Jenkins has a console that runs Groovy scripts on the remote slave. I've been playing with it a bit, but not many conclusions so far. Maybe that helps.

---

This may be important; this is the shebang I'm using for the Ruby scripts: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

---

On the terminal, I'm using the same user as Jenkins is to access the slave machine. It's called "jenkins".

---

One thing I forgot to mention is that the output is telling me the right version: `/Users/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0`. At least that's the path it's indicating it's trying to load the gem from. So I tried the following:

```
: /Users/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby
require 'xcodeproj'
```

Then I press ctrl+D and get no output - that installation of ruby is finding the gem properly.

Comment: It's not necessary, and not desirable, to use "Edit" or "Update" tags in your text. Instead, put the information into the text where it would have been if you'd added it originally. We can see where, and when, you changed the text if we need to.

Comment: You can't use `/usr/bin/env ruby` and get consistent results across different accounts and systems unless they are configured identically, which is unlikely when using Jenkins. `env` looks inside the PATH to find Ruby and returns the first Ruby found. Unless you're setting your PATH and have installed the same Ruby as you use locally odds are good Jenkins is finding a Ruby installed by the OS in /usr/bin/ruby. You'll need to check to see what Jenkins is using vs your local system when you build manually.

Comment: Well, yes, but how? I understand I need to know which installation Jenkins is running, I just don't know how to do it. Ideas?

Comment: That would be a separate question about Jenkins.

Comment: I don't see how... That's the only thing I asked: `Basically what I need is to install gems for the same Ruby environment that Jenkins is using, but I don't know which one that is. Any ideas?`

Comment: Shouldn't you be telling Jenkins which version of Ruby to use, not the other way around?

Comment: Definitely! And I also tried that. Basically I changed the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/ruby`. Oddly, I got the same result...

Comment: Worst. I ran `gem env` from Jenkins and got the path `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby` under `RUBY EXECUTABLE`. Then I tested with the full path using the command line and it worked from the terminal; still doesn't from Jenkins.

Comment: Run `type jenkins`, or `which jenkins` in Terminal to see which one you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jenkins Slave plugin to communicate between Jenkins Master and Jenkins Slave, every command that u specify will be run in non-interactive shell. That means that Jenkins will only have access to system ruby in your case.

So if you want to install something that needs to be installed you have to do it in system ruby. You are using rvm so: `rvm use system` and you can install gem to system ruby.

If you want to use different Ruby version than system ruby you need to add RVM to $PATH for non-interactive shell. Here is basic setup that should help: https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Comment: Ah! Makes perfect sense. So I know what to do. I'll give it a try. One thing I noticed is that my system ruby is 2.0.0, but for what I need it's required 2.2.2. That must have been the trigger for the whole thing. I also noticed that `gem` (using `gem env`) gives quite different results. I'll try and update the system install and get back with results. Thank you!

Comment: The problem persists... I've edited both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` but neither seems to be loaded by the Jenkins runner. I also tried `rvm --default use 2.4`. Is there a way I can change the system version of ruby?

Comment: @AndréFratelli I had a problem like yours with Gradle and Jenkins and I edited '/etc/environment' to include path to Gradle and Jenkins could use it in Pipeline steps in non-interactive shell.

Comment: I finally managed it! Thank you immensely for your help, it was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed it. As @Cosaquee indicated in another response, it's important to distinguish between interactive and non-interactive shells. The main reason for this is because, depending on how you call SSH, it makes a difference. As the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) indicates:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of
>   a login shell.

This is meaningful, because the Launch Command for the node I have set for Jenkins is this one:

```
ssh jenkins@x.x.x.x java -jar ~/bin/slave.jar
```

In the meanwhile, I was logging in with the standard `ssh jenkins@x.x.x.x` from the terminal, which starts a login shell. It makes sense that I was getting different results because the two shells [load different initial scripts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc). Basically, if you use `ssh jenkins@x.x.x.x` to login into the machine `~/.bash_profile` is loaded, while if you specify a command, such as `ssh jenkins@x.x.x.x whatever`, then `~/.bashrc` is loaded instead. As such, I added this line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Without it I got:

> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not
>   work.

The advantage was that I could now use RVM from the same environment Jenkins was using. The rest is easy:

```
ssh jenkins@x.x.x.x rvm --default use 2.3
```

And:

```
ssh jenkins@x.x.x.x
rvm --default use 2.3
```

And both are now using the same version of ruby.